# How to redirect url to url not by IP?

Tags: browser, website, redirection

`hosts` file does not support **url to url** syntax, only **url to ip**.
Ubuntu 12.04

Comment: Correction: `hosts` file does not support URL to *anything*. It only works with "host to ip" kind of redirections.

Comment: oh, yes, I need exactly *url* to ip.

Comment: For `url-to-ip` you should think about `DNS`; and now your comment not longer matches your question... url-to-url? url-to-ip? please get your intent clear and then update the question itself.

Comment: damn, **URL TO URL**!
site1.com/url1 to site1.com/url2

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Setup local web server (Apache would be fine).
2. Use host file to point URL to local IP.
3. Use Apache's mod_rewrite to rewrite the URL. Or, you can put an index.html file in the DocumentRoot of web server & redirect using JavaScript or HTML meta refresh.
   You can also go one step further to install PHP and redirect URL using index.php.

Comment: For step 3, you can get codes with one Google search (if you don't know how to do that). Or, just ask me for baked codes. At this time, I am on mobile so unable to type codes quickly.